# How to loop through json without an array

Tags: ansible

I am trying to work out how to iterate over some JSON that has repeated structures but have not used a list.

I am using the `ansible.posix.firewalld_info` module and it returns a dictionary for each zone:

```
{
"active_zones": true,
    "changed": false,
    "collected_zones": [
        "public",
        "work"
    ],
    "firewalld_info": {
        "default_zone": "public",
        "version": "0.9.3",
        "zones": {
            "public": {
                "forward": false,
                "forward_ports": [],
                "icmp_block_inversion": false,
                "icmp_blocks": [],
                "interfaces": [
                    "ens22",
                    "ens20",
                    "ens19",
                    "ens18"
                ],
                "masquerade": true,
                "ports": [
                    [
                        "9090",
                        "tcp"
                    ]
                ],
                "protocols": [],
                "rich_rules": [],
                "services": [
                    "ssh",
                    "cockpit",
                    "MyCustomService"
                ],
                "source_ports": [],
                "sources": [],
                "target": "DROP"
            },
            "work": {
                "forward": false,
                "forward_ports": [],
                "icmp_block_inversion": false,
                "icmp_blocks": [],
                "interfaces": [
                    "ens21"
                ],
                "masquerade": false,
                "ports": [],
                "protocols": [],
                "rich_rules": [],
                "services": [
                    "ssh",
                    "dhcpv6-client",
                    "cockpit"
                ],
                "source_ports": [],
                "sources": [],
                "target": "default"
            }
        }
    },
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "active_zones": true,
            "zones": null
        }
    },
    "undefined_zones": []
}
```

`public` and `work` are dictionaries. How can I iterate over each zone under `firewalld_info` in this JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: *"**How can I iterate over each zone?**"*

A: Convert the dictionary to a list, .e.g. given the data in the variable *result*

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ result.firewalld_info.zones.public|dict2items }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  item:
    key: forward
    value: false

  item:
    key: forward_ports
    value: []

  item:
    key: icmp_block_inversion
    value: false

  ...
```

See [with_dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-dict)

Comment: Thanks. Great answer

Answer (score 1):

Since Vladimir answered this in the ansible context I'm going to give you a way to process this in the shell.

As a one liner:

```
for zone in public work; do echo "another iteration"; cat fw.json | jq ".firewalld_info.zones.$zone"; done
```

Or as prettier code:

```
for zone in public work
do 
        echo "another iteration"
        cat fw.json | jq ".firewalld_info.zones.$zone"
        # save it in a variable or pass it through another round of jq to extract details into variables
done
```

You're using `jq` to extract the subsections you want.  The biggest limitation of these examples is that the zones are hard-coded.  You can pull [the keys out with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23118607/2002471) to make this more flexible.